# Practical design pattern to execute tasks that block awaiting on the result of subtasks?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

I'm trying to see if its possible to take generic (serial) algorithms, and make them execute in an parallel and distributed manner, simply by annotating key functions. Goals:

1. there should be no need to make major structural reorganization of the  the algorithm to accommodate parallelism, and
2. I should be able to have my algorithm run serially (=debuggable) by making the annotation a no-op.
3. I'd like the compute-resource to not care too much about the specifics of the task being executed.

This is trivial for simple tasks, but not obvious for tasks with dependent computation that we also want to distribute. Suppose I have as task:

```
@distributed(pool)
def task1()
   # Task1 has dependent, distributed computation
   # Cannot return until a and b are both computed by subtasks
   a = task2(11)
   b = task2(22)

   # Continue and do more processing, which may be
   # complex and time consuming:
   result = a + b

   return result


@distributed(pool)
def task2(x): .... return x*10
```

The annotation @distributed takes care of *serialization* of the call to the wrapped task function and, its parameters, and returns the result.

The above has the problem that:

```
   a = task2(11)
   b = task2(22)
```

are submitted to the pool sequentially, and doesn't benefit from parallelism. So, let's assume we fix it in one of two ways:

- `@distributed` returns a future and doesn't block until the value of the result is evaluated.  (We must call `a.await()+b.await()`), OR
- we explicitly reference the pool:

  ```
   a,b = pool.map(task2, [(11,), (22,)])
  ```

  and pool.map knows that when is sees a @distributed, it should 'do the right thing' and distribute the wrapped function.

OK, a little soft of requirement (1), but so far, simple enough.

The difficulty this pattern has is that, if `pool` only has, say, 2 available workers, and I submitted 2x`task1`, then when `task2` is submitted to the pool, we risk a **deadlock**: `task2` cannot execute because both workers are busy executing `task1` and waiting on its result.

What's a good pattern to resolve this problem so that I can have a single (distributed) worker pool to execute all my jobs with the minimum of intrusion to my code.

---

Common solutions:

- one topic(/task type) per worker: having one groups of workers per type of work avoids deadlock in the above situation, but does not in general case where tasks are recursive (e.g. decision tree building). It's also pretty gross in that we have to define which workers work on what tasks (fails 3). Akka and AMPQ based systems seems to work this way.
- Theadpools can solve the deadlock problem thusly:

  - if the pool has no free workers, don't submit the job to the pool, then execute it immediately without submitting it to the pool. Works great, but its less clear how to make this work in a distributed environment since the decision of whether to submit to the queue or execute locally need a global transaction.

I feel like I'm missing a good pattern here, the would help me avoid refactoring a lot of code to be distributable.